# Using a third party lib with cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, qr-code, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to implement a third party library into a cakePHP 2.0 project.
I would like to use the [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) library to create QRCodes.

I made a new folder in `app/Plugin` called `QrCode` and put the library in the `Vendor` folder of my new plugin.

I created a component in `Controller/Component` called `QrGeneratorComponent` with this content:

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'phpqrcode'.DS.'qrlib');

// Component defined in 'QrCode' plugin
class QrGeneratorComponent extends Component {

    public function test() {
        return QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
    }
}
```

In my application I added the component `public $components = array('QrCode.QrGenerator');` and tried to access my test-method: `$this->QrGenerator->test();`

But I always get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'QRcode' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\app\Plugin\QrCode\Controller\Component\QrGeneratorComponent.php on line 8

So, what did I wrong? Is there a better way to implement a third party library?

Comment: It's better to use a `Helper` instead of `Component`. Because it's in `View`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to prefix the vendor path with the plugin name: `App::import('Vendor', 'QrCode.phpqrcode'.DS.'qrlib');`